# Does there exist a valid way to specify a paralist without giving a format for a counter?

Tags: counters, warnings, paralist

For the following input...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}

\begin{inparaenum}[]
\item This is sentence one.
\item This is sentence two.
\end{inparaenum}

\end{document}
```

... I (understandably) get the following warning:

```
Package paralist Warning: Incorrect label; no or multiple counters.
(paralist)                The label is:  on input line 5.
```

Is there a way to keep the structure but specify this in a way that does not give a warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just use an `inparaitem` instead of `inparaenum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}

\begin{inparaitem}[]
\item This is sentence one.
\item This is sentence two.
\end{inparaitem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is mostly implied. If you don't want an enumeration, don't use an enumeration. The other option is an itemization.

Comment: It is, but I used Google before using my brain and now hopefully the next person will now not have to use their brain at all! Sigh...

Comment: @aronisstav Thanks! This was what I just needed.